# Given matrices A and B, how does one find C such that $ C^{-1}AC = B$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Given matrices A and B, how does one find C such that $ C^{-1}AC = B$ ?

Comment: In general it's impossible, since you need $\det A = \det B$.

Comment: By finding eigenvectors for $A$ and $B$ ... [more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity)

Comment: Reduce them to rational canonical forms.